# Max number of items in recycler view Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How many items a recycler view can display before failing out of memory? thousand? millions?

I am not specifying if the recycler will display items all at once or chunks because at the end (if keep scrolling) all the items will be loaded.

Thank you

Comment: I recommend you reading about Recycler View. https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/understanding-recyclerview-part-1-the-basics-a7bd07cfae93. All the items are not loaded, Views are reused to show new data. So it should never go out of memory.

Comment: @AkshayMahajan I have read it. Doesnt say what i ask. Sorry.... It says only that it recycles views..good... What about the size of ArrayList that holds the data before putting them into the adapter?

Comment: Then your question is not related to Recycler view, it's related to ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, RecyclerView will not load all the items whatever how you scroll. It **reuses** the old views or creates new so many how it needs and then just reuses them. Also for optimization, RecyclerView uses **ViewHolder pattern**. I suggest you to read more about it

Answer (score 4):

I have tested with at least 90k items,but not failed,no OOM. My item contains imageview(managed by fresco),5 textview,1 static small icon.

Comment: So loading all these items at once will be fine?

Comment: well, technically RC view will not load all. It will only load the items within viewable area. Also it recycles the old views for re using. Only the load in memory will come is the total size of your objects(in my answer which is 90k obj). That wont be that big for causing OOM. And If you use fresco as I said for image handling. Then it will be absolutely fine.